# Bulk Delete Tags does not remove all of them

Tags: finder, finder-tag

I am trying to delete a bunch of unneeded tags.  I go to Finders Prefs to select the tags

[image]

I then select delete and am given the warning

[image]

I select Delete Tags.  Some of them are removed, but others hang around

[image]

Comment: try, try, try again. I've seen the same thing - it'll begrudgingly delete them all eventually